# Implement a custom init with added custom parameters in subclass, in Swift

Tags: swift, subclass, init

I'm trying to create a subclass in which I will add more functions and properties to the `SCNParticleSystem` object.

The `SCNParticleSystem` header file in Swift has only this `init` declared:

```
public convenience init?(named name: String, inDirectory directory: String?)
```

So, what I want to do is use the same parameters as the `init` but also add a custom parameter to the `init` like this and do some setup for my properties:

```
init how ? (particleSystemFileName:String, inDirectory:String, parentNode:SCNNode)
{
    init who ?

    <setup my stuff>
}
```

I just can't figure out how to do this?

thx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's just not possible to create convenience init from subclass to call convenience init in superclass. Why? Initializers has to follow 3 rules:

1. *A designated initializer must call a designated initializer from its
   immediate superclass.*
2. *A convenience initializer must call another initializer from the
   same class.*
3. *A convenience initializer must ultimately call a designated
   initializer.*

Diagram that shows what you can actually do with initializers & subclassing ([more on that topic](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html)):

[image]

What you can do is some sort of `setup()` method that will customize your created instance of a subclass with given properties.

Comment: Thanks, thats what I have to go with for now.